# Android "adb install" does nothing

Tags: android, apk, adb

I'm having trouble installing a simple .apk file using adb.  Here's what I entered and got back:

```
adb install test.apk
4445 KB/s (1921193 bytes in 0.422s)
```

In an attempt to debug I added the trace flag and got back:

```
adb install test.apk ADB_TRACE=1
4445 KB/s (1921193 bytes in 0.422s)
Aborted
```

Also, the `adb devices` command does list my device and when I manually copy the .apk to my device it installs/runs fine.

Help :(

Comment: what do you think `adb install test.apk ADB_TRACE=1` should do exactly?

Comment: I was hoping for detailed output so I could troubleshoot the issue.  It looks like `adb kill-server` -> `set ADB_TRACE=1` -> `adb start-server` -> `adb install test.apk` gives me the output I really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what was going on, but after a system update it now works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

adb install -r test.apk

or you need to enable to insatll unknown source app in android settings.